# wpfでの動作アプリケーションのミュート

Tags: c#, wpf

作成したアプリケーションだけをミュート、アンミュートしたいのですが、良い方法はないでしょうか。
アプリケーションにはブラウザが含まれており、ブラウザ内のFlashなどもまとめてミュートしたいです。
音声ミキサーのアプリケーション単位のミュート動作が合致します。
一応、Vannatec.CoreAudio.dllを使う方法はありましたが、できれば外部dll無しの方法が今後を考えるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

具体的に同等の実装を行ったことがないので、基本的にポインター提供のみとなります。

要は Windows の Core Audio API を叩ければいいので、Vannatec.CoreAudio.dll がどういう挙動を取っているかは分かりませんが、おそらくほぼ同等の事を行えば良いかと思います。名前的にも Windows Core Audio API を叩いてるのでしょうし。

という点で言うと、https://blog.sverrirs.com/2016/02/windows-coreaudio-api-in-c.html ……にある https://gist.github.com/sverrirs/d099b34b7f72bb4fb386 が参考になるように思えます。
GetVolumeObject() 内でプロセス列挙して実際の API コールは SetApplicationMute() 辺りで行っている形ですね。

ここで取得している IAudioSessionControl2::GetProcessId() から得られるプロセス ID が (Win32 API 的な) CreateProcess() 的なプロセス ID であれば、単に自身のプロセス ID を指定して mute 操作を行えば大丈夫かと思います。そうでなかったとしても、GetVolumeObject() 内で列挙して取得しているので、その辺りが十分に参考になるかと思います。

ただ、Core Audio になってから「音を鳴らしていないアプリは音量ミキサーの一覧に出てくるのを見たことがない」ので、もしかしたら GetVolumeObject() で行っている ISimpleAudioVolume オブジェクトを直接プロセス ID を指定しても取得できないかもしれないので、もしかしたらその辺りにちょっと工夫がいるかもしれません。
単にシステム音を鳴らす (例えば System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play(); で鳴らす) だけのアプリなどは出てきませんので、別途前準備が必要になるかもしれません。

Comment: 紹介していただいたコードでWin10にて動作を確認できました。